# I wanted to move my modem but the cable from ISP is too short, how to extend? Details and picture inside

Tags: networking, router, modem, fiber

So I want to move my modem from my room to another room. The problem is the cable is too short and I don't know how to extend this cable because it's not an ethernet cable. See pictures below:

This is the cable that came from the pole outside my house, it looks like telephone pole or maybe fiber optic?? I'm not sure

[image: https://i.imgur.com/1kdkBrH.jpg]

The cable from picture 1 will be merged with some kind of yellow color cable and then plugged into the modem

[image: https://i.imgur.com/KAfIIV1.jpg]

[image: https://i.imgur.com/Y0xDtMr.jpg]

So my question is how do I extend this cable? I want to rip those ghetto style cable to check what's in it but I'm afraid if I can't put it back in, my gf will kill me because that means no phone, no internet, and no TV cable.

Note: My ISP gave me this additional cable, can I use this to extend?

[image: https://i.imgur.com/LZ5utDG.jpg]

Any help will be appreciated.

UPDATE: Here's the close up pictures of the yellow and black cable merging.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ask your ISP. It looks like they installed the strange cable. Is it spliced where it changes from black to yellow or is there a plug and socket there? Can you provide a closeup of this area?

Comment: no plug or socket, I think it's spliced. Please check my updated post

Comment: What is the green connector on your modem? You should be able to buy an extension cable with a socket on one end (where you can plug in the blue plug) and a plug on the other end (where you can plug in the new cable). You ISP should be able to tell you what kind of cable you need.

Comment: I would just try if the extension cord plugs fits. It's definitly fiber, so watch out to not touch the contact surfaces and to not overbend it (keep ~5cm of radius!)

Comment: I believe it's the same connector like picture : https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVKbT.jpg

Or you can see this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fg1CYPSW5Pc#t=1m11s

It has the same connector like in the video.

What's the extension cable called? That's what I'm trying to find out.

I tried calling the customer service but most of them is just your typical CS with no networking background. They can send a technician to my house but it takes up to a week. Thought I would just do it myself.

Comment: From the pictures it looks like an SC connector for fibre. It could be extended with something like this: http://www.cablestogo.com/product/27098/sc-female-to-sc-female-duplex-fiber-optic-adapter - the page also lists a range of products which could be used: http://www.cablestogo.com/category/fiber/fiber-adapters-accessories/fiber-adapters dependant on what cables you use. I wouldn't reccomend doing anything with the existing splicing, as it's definitly not done as it should be.

Comment: So to make sure, this is what I should get right? Since my SC connector only have one line (simplex). http://www.cablestogo.com/product/17437/sc-sc-f-f-simplex-fiber-optic-coupler

Comment: I would say so, yes! Just confirm by reading labels on the packaging that it is indeed SC connectors.